# Max rocket speed in interstellar space?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, rocket-science

Interstellar space propulsion...if a spaceship were to get beyond our Sun's gravitational pull and since there is no atmosphere/wind/friction in space...does that mean, if an engine was constantly thrusting, that the spaceship would continue to accelerate to the speed of light, as long as the engine was propulsing forward?  In other words, does speed constantly increase in a vacuum? or are the two ideas (Space/Vacuum) separate ideas?

Comment: The wording of this question is slightly imprecise. For instance, the expression _constantly thrusting_ just implies a positive rocket engine thrust, that may vary in time, not necessarily a constant thrust. Similarly _speed constantly increase_ (in 1D) means positive acceleration, not necessarily a constant acceleration. Also the question can be interpreted as just asking about _approaching_ the speed of light, not actually achieving light speed.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, according to [Einstein's Theory of Relativity](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/rocket.html).

> As an object approaches the speed of light, more and more energy is needed to accelerate it further.  To reach the speed of light an infinite amount of energy would be required.

Also, there is wind/friction in space. There is no absolute vacuum, there is an [interstellar medium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium). Indeed, relativistic rockets would have to account for the medium, and perhaps even use it as a source of fuel, see: [Bussard Ramjet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet).

Comment: That would be great except Einstein's theory will be proven to be inaccurate or incomplete, if not wholly wrong, within 50 years. In science, no is just another word for haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @BBlake, if it can't be proved wrong today, how can you put a time-frame on when it will happen?

Comment: Because I'm an optimist!

Comment: @ghoppe, And at relativistic speeds, tiny particles become like atomic bombs.

Comment: @BBlake Your optimism is admirable, but the chances of the Theory of Relativity being proven "wrong" within 50 years are about equal to the chances of the Theory of Evolution being proven "wrong." It's been quite rigorously tested. The ability to travel faster than light opens quite a few paradoxes that are rather difficult to resolve.

Comment: @BBlake: I would say that the theory of relativity is likely to be proved incomplete, but it is accurate so far as we know today. But if you want to debate that, ask another question:-)

Comment: @ghoppe - There is a more limiting constraint.  Namely, the combustion rate of the fuel or the momentum flux of the burning fuel.  Rocket fuel does not burn infinitely fast and even if we ignored fuel consumption, a rocket propelled by traditional fuel could never come close to reaching the speed of light.  The exhaust pushing the rocket isn't even a significant fraction of c.

Answer (score 2):

You asked three questions...

1.) ... does that mean, if an engine was constantly thrusting, that the spaceship would continue to accelerate to the speed of light, as long as the engine was propulsing forward?

No. For reasons ghoppe gave.

2.) ... In other words, does speed constantly increase in a vacuum?

Yes, speed would increase continuously, for the example you gave, asymtotically approaching (but never reaching) the speed of light.

3.) ... or are the two ideas (Space/Vacuum) seperate ideas?

No.  A vacuum is an excellent and practical description of what most space is.

Comment: I would disagree slightly with your third point. Space is mostly a vacuum, but there is enough matter that if you were going, say, 90%+ the speed of light, it would start to make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that our perceptions of Relativity hold up in interstellar space...

The ship would continue to accelerate as long as fuel held out.

Speed would continue its asymptotic clime towards C...

until drag was sufficient to end that climb. Drag would also increase due to interstellar medium collisions as speed increased. But note also: a sufficiently high thrust will not be exceeded by drag.

Note that as speed increases, and drag increases, so does radiation. The interstellar medium results in Alpha & Beta radiation increases, and high energy photon releases from same producing X-ray and even gamma radiation.

Note that several science fiction works have relativity have a cutoff point. In a few more, Relativity is ignored entirely; the most egregious offender is E.E. "Doc" Smith's *Lensmen* series. John Ringo's Looking Glass series has heliopause boundary changes to the nature of physics, including relativity

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself; you say that drag will end that climb, yet you say that high thrust will beat the drag.  The true issue here are the relativistic kinematics at hand.  Velocities don't add like we expect them to at relativistic speeds.

Comment: Drag is limited due to the asymptotic approach; the drag is the mass of particles hit, which is directly proportional to speed. If thrust is low (like ion drives), it will limit speed to .99C or so; if thrust is high, the balance point would be superluminal, and thus not actually stop the speed climb towards C.

Answer (score -1):

A rocket-powered vehicle is always going to be limited by its own propulsion system.
If we assume infinite fuel loads [plus a bit more for the rocket] then intuitively we can see that if all of the fuel is instantaneously expelled at the speed of light, the rocket can exceed the speed of light (if we ignore relativistic effects for a moment.)
However this is impractical - the fuel will always take a finite amount of time to burn, so during that time it also has to propel the remaining fuel, i.e. on average half of the thrust is used to accelerate the rocket, and half to accelerate the fuel, giving a practical limit of half light-speed, and that is assuming perfect combustion, which is itself not realistic, even with Newtonian physics.

Comment: Looks like I over-simplified. That link talks about theoretical limits, but I was trying to point out the practical limits too.

Comment: Yes, the fuel requirements to approach lightspeed are huge. You can read details in the classic Usenet [relativistic rocket](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html) article. But even getting halfway there is pretty hard. Eg, if you could magically beam power to a ship to increase its kinetic energy, so it doesn't have to carry fuel or reaction mass, it'd use almost a year's worth of Earth's current energy production to accelerate a 15,000 tonne ship to .5c.